# In CD pipeline from drop folder need to download specific file not entire drop folder

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In CD pipeline I am using **Download Build Artifact** task to download artifacts to destination directory. My Publish artifact directory structure is as below

drop --> Source --> abc.zip

Now the problem is whenever I download artifact it download entire drop folder and place same structure in destination directory. But what I want is to Place only "abc.zip" to my destination directory. Where I don't want "drop" and "Source" folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that the **Download Build Artifact** task couldn't only download the specific file from Build artifacts.

I suggest that you can change to use the task [Download Pipeline Artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) and set the `Matching patterns` to `**/**/abc.zip`

Here is an example:

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  displayName: 'Download Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    buildType: specific
    project: 'project'
    definition: 610
    artifactName: drop
    itemPattern: '**/**/abc.zip'
    targetPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

Classic:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response and appreciated your efforts. I have tried doing the same but it always placing "abc.zip" inside drop folder. I don't want drop folder. I directly want abc.zip inside my destination directory

Comment: When I use the Download Pipeline artifacts task, it could work fine. It only download the abc.zip file. Can you try this task?

Comment: What I have observed that Pattern I am trying is working for Download Pipeline Artifacts  task, but it is not working for Download Build Artifact task. Don't know why is it so. But I will manage with Download Pipeline Artifact task. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @Milan Great! Glad to know that it could work for you. You may consider accept this answer if it could work for you. This may help other users with the same requirement.